# Analytic continuation of an integral

Tags: cv.complex-variables, analytic-continuation

Let 
$$f(y)=\frac{y_1^{1/3}y_2^{1/3}}{y_1+y_2+1}$$.
Consider the following integral:
$$F(s_1,s_2)=\int_{\mathbb{R}_+^2}f(y)^{s_1}f(y^{-1})^{s_2}\frac{dy_1dy_2}{y_1y_2}$$
where $y^{-1}=(y_1^{-1},y_2^{-1})$. This integral is absolutely convergent for $\Re(s_i)>0$.

Interesting fact: If we let either $s_1=0$ or $s_2=0$, we can write $F(s_1,0)$ (or $F(0,s_2)$) in terms of Gamma functions. Those expression suggest that $F$ has a pole at $(0,0)$.

I expect that $F$ has analytic continuation beyond the zero lines. But I do not see a way to  write it in some closed form, possibly with integrals.

Since it is somehow connected with Gamma functions, integration by parts is a natural idea to try out. Maybe I missed something, or some other observation is needed.

Comment: Does $\mathbb{R}^2_+$ consist of points $(y_1,y_2)$ with $y_1\ge 0$ and $y_2 \ge 0$?

Comment: @ChristianRemling Yes, what you say is true. This function $F$ comes up in my research of some asymptotic behavior. Vaguely speaking, some expression of $F$ for negative s1 and s2 is needed to estimate the term after I move the line of integration.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine Yes. Maybe I should write double integral $\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty$

Comment: @ChristianRemling at least I want to find some growth condition for $F$ beyond zero.